# Configuration Change for Incremental Model on DBT

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

On one our previously created incremental models, I added `partition_by` and `partition_expiration_days` parameters to the configuration to set the table partition and retention in place.

```
{{ config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='record_id',
        on_schema_change='append_new_columns',
        partition_by={
              "field": "row_ts",
              "data_type": "timestamp",
              "granularity": "day"
        },
        partition_expiration_days = 365
        )
}}
```

I observed on the next run that the configuration didn't applied to the table.

It seems a `full-refresh` operation needed here. Yet we have strict retention on the data source for this table which some of the data would be lost with `full-refresh` operation.

Could anyone please let me know how this issue can be addressed with a solution?

Comment: None of the on_schema_change behaviors backfill values in old records for newly added columns. If you need to populate those values, we recommend running manual updates or triggering a --full-refresh. But it depends on the number of tables we have to update.

Comment: There is no schema change in this case. Adding a partition to a table is the question here for DBT. It seems DBT doesn't support this in the first place. It doesn't hide the complexity of background operations when adding a partition to a table in BigQuery.